# Prevent multirow cell overflow with dynamic cell content

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, programming

I have the following table layout:
[image: Layout schematic]

The table consists of 3 columns - one column which is 25% wide, and two columns that take up equal amounts of the space left (thus 37.5% each).

The content for these columns is obtained from programmatic variables, which can vary in length quite a bit.
Thus, each table cell should be able to process manual line breaks in the variable strings that get passed in, as well as automatic line breaks based on content length.

I've tried a couple different approaches, and the closest thing I've managed to a working example is included below, using multirow and nested tabular environments inside a tabularx for the width:
MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{4cm}|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{
        \begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}
            One Line\\
            Two Lines
        \end{tabular}
    } & 
    \multirow{3}{*}{
        \begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}
            Lots of text goes here\\
            Lots of text here indeed lel lel lol aaa ss bzxbg
        \end{tabular}
    } & 
    \multirow{3}{*}{
        \begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}
            Lots of text go here\\
            In fact, tons of text go here\\
            So much text, in fact, that you'd have to do weird cell padding things to fix it\\
            AAAA\\
            BBBB\\
            CCCC\\
            DDDD\\
            EEEE
        \end{tabular}
    } \\
    \cline{1-1}
    \begin{tabular}[l]{@{}c@{}}
        This line here will overlap \\
        AA
    \end{tabular} & & \\ 
    \cline{1-1}
    \begin{tabular}[l]{@{}c@{}}
        One Line\\
        Two Lines\\
        Three Lines
    \end{tabular} & & 
    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

This layout has some issues, as can be seen below:
[image: Annotated LaTeX issues]

While the manual line breaks work, longer lines don't automatically break once they fill out the cells, instead overflowing on the side.

The two cells on the right also don't cause the multirow cells to resize, instead overflowing at the bottom. (the cells inside the multirow do cause a resize - if they are longer, the rightmost two cells do correctly resize downward)

The alignment + padding isn't 100% either.

Are there any simple mistakes one can easily fix in my MWE, or different approaches to multirow content that can dynamically resize? The usual answer is to match your multirow content to the number of lines in the largest cell. I can't do that here, as I do not know in advance which cell that will end up being, since the fields contain dynamic content.

Comment: Try to replace tabulars with tabularx environments so that you have nested tabularx's. Other than the l,r,c columns, the X column supports automatic linebreaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this is what you like to have?

[image]

Your problem is nested tables and `multirow`s in `tabularx` columns, which override defined columns types. Removing nested tabulars and use new syntax for `multirow` (see code below) MWE with your table is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{4cm}|X|X|}
    \hline
One Line

Two Lines   
    &   \multirow[t]{8}{=}{Lots of text goes here
                           Lots of text here indeed lel lel lol aaa ss bzxbg
                        }
    &   \multirow[t]{8}{=}{Lots of text go here In fact, tons of text go here
                        So much text, in fact, that you'd have to do weird cell padding things to fix it\newline
                        AAAA\newline
                        BBBB\newline
                        CCCC\newline
                        DDDD\newline
                        EEEE\newline
                        }   \\
    \cline{1-1}
 This line here will overlap 

        AA
    &   &               \\
    \cline{1-1}
One Line 

Two Lines

Three Lines
    &   &               \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Another possibility is not to use `\multirow` cells and instead it nest `tabular` table in the first column:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|@{} p{4cm}  |X|X|}
    \hline
\begin{tabular}[t]{ >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\hsize-\tabcolsep} }
One Line    \\
Two Lines   \\  \hline
This line here will overlap (no longer) \\
AA          \\ \hline
One Line    \\
Two Lines   \\
Three Lines 
\end{tabular} 
    &   Lots of text goes here
        Lots of text here indeed lel lel lol aaa ss bzxbg
    &   Lots of text go here In fact, tons of text go here So much text, in fact, that you'd have to
        do weird cell padding things to fix it

        AAAA

        BBBB

        CCCC

        DDDD

        EEEE    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's close, but there are 2 issues
- The two columns on the right should be top-left aligned, and they're instead center-left aligned
- The content is dynamic, it can't be assumed that the multirow will be 8 lines long

Comment: @WynandMarais, corrected.

Comment: I accidentally hit enter instead of shift-enter, my apologies - the comment has been edited.

For posterity, it is copy-pasted below:
-----
That's close, but there are 2 issues - The two columns on the right should be top-left aligned, and they're instead center-left aligned - The content is dynamic, it can't be assumed that the multirow will be 8 lines long

Comment: If text will be longer than 8 lines, than will spill out of table. The cures are (i) insert fake rows, which span `multirow` cells or make rows in the first column higher, or (ii) not use `multirow` cells and in the first column nest table with correct defined column.

Comment: @WynandMarais, see addendum to answer.

Comment: Accepted for the addendum - thank you very much for the help